# Expected Regression Coefficent in return space

Tags: interpretation, regression-coefficients, finance

Say you are running a regression on predicting the future 1 second return(new price / curr_price - 1)/ using the return of past 1 Milli second, what is the expected range of coefficient in this case? Or more specifically what values of coefficient would warrant you checking your code for bug? Can assume price of an instrument is a log normal distribution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The core of the question requires practical knowledge of finance, so Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange might be a better place to ask this question.